# AWS-CDK & Powershell Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have a Powershell Lambda that I would like to deploy via the AWS CDK however I'm having issues getting it to run.

Deploying the Powershell via a manual Publish-AWSPowerShellLambda works:

```
Publish-AWSPowerShellLambda -ScriptPath .\PowershellLambda.ps1 -Name PowershellLambda
```

However the same script deployed with the CDK doesnt log to CloudWatch Logs, even though it has permission:

```
import events = require('@aws-cdk/aws-events');
import targets = require('@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets');
import lambda = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda');
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');

export class LambdaCronStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(app: cdk.App, id: string) {
    super(app, id);

    const lambdaFn = new lambda.Function(this, 'Singleton', {      
      code: new lambda.AssetCode('./PowershellLambda/PowershellLambda.zip'),
      handler: 'PowershellLambda::PowershellLambda.Bootstrap::ExecuteFunction',
      timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300),
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.DOTNET_CORE_2_1
    });

    const rule = new events.Rule(this, 'Rule', {
      schedule: events.Schedule.expression('rate(1 minute)')
    });

    rule.addTarget(new targets.LambdaFunction(lambdaFn));
  }
}

const app = new cdk.App();
new LambdaCronStack(app, 'LambdaCronExample');
app.synth();
```

The powershell script currently contains just the following lines and works when deployed by Publish-AWSPowerShellLambda on the CLI:

```
#Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='AWSPowerShell.NetCore';ModuleVersion='3.3.335.0'}
Write-Host "Powershell Lambda Executed"
```

Note: For the CDK Deployment I generate the .zip file using a build step in package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build-package": "pwsh -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command New-AWSPowerShellLambdaPackage -ScriptPath './PowershellLambda/PowershellLambda.ps1' -OutputPackage ./PowershellLambda/PowershellLambda.zip",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  }
```

The CDK deploys fine and the Lambda runs as expected but the only thing in Cloudwatch Logs is this:
**START RequestId: 4c12fe1a-a9e0-4137-90cf-747b6aecb639 Version: $LATEST**

I've checked that the Handler in the CDK script matches the output of the Publish-AWSPowerShellLambda and that the zip file uploaded fine and contains the correct code.

Any suggestions as to why this isnt working?

Comment: Can you share the "PowershellLambda.ps1" file of yours ? I am trying to deploy the same but getting error !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the memory size to 512mb within the lambda.Function has resolved the issue.

The cloudwatch entry showed the lambda starting but it appears there wasn't enough memory to initialize and run the .net runtime.